# Stopping Netbeans uploading filesystem changes

Tags: netbeans

I have a project that is synced up to a remote (SFTP) server.

I don't want NetBeans to automatically upload all changes that are made on the filesystem (e.g. a svn update). Files that I saved in the IDE I would want to go up.

Is there any easy way to make this happen? 
(my workaround now is to change the project to upload "on run" and then upload files manually from the project view. It would be nice if there were a more automatic way of doing this)